# .map is not a function error with TypeScript array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I'm trying to make a simple loop, so I can log the data in the console:

```
const demands = data.myDemand;
  console.log(demands);
```

```
//First approach
demands.map((demand) => {
  console.log(demand);
});
```

```
 //Second approach
 Array.prototype.forEach.call(demands, (demand) => {
   console.log(demand);
 });
```

Using the first approach I receive the following error:

```
TypeError: demands.map is not a function
```

And the second approach just displays nothing.
What could be the problem? Logging the whole demands data in the console, I receive this output:

[image]

The general Idea is that I want to map this data that's coming from the backend to the props in the current react component but I am not able to get the mapping to works since I need to go through this array of objects, in which some of the objects also contain array of objects...

Comment: Seems like `demands` is not an array. Based on the debugging screenshot, `demands` is an object.

Comment: It isn't an array. You can tell because when you log it it has `{}` around it and not `[]`.

Comment: Yours `demands` seems to be a Map (object) and not an array of objects. You can try `Object.values(demands).map(demand => console.log(demand))`